# Как прописать в Css изменение стилей дочерних элем :hover родителя

Tags: css, hover

При наведении на `footer` нужно сменить стиль у нескольких ссылок, для каждой ссылки свой стиль.

Такой код не работает.

```
 .foot-l:hover {
  span.phone-box a {
    color: #fff900
  }
  span.adres-box a {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3dff00;
  }
  span.mail-box a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #00ceff;
  }
}
```

Скажите как правильно объединить или что почитать?

Comment: вы используете класс, а нужно использовать идентификатор

Comment: @digital Можно подробнее что именно изменить ?

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что это должно работать? Вы используете Less или SCSS??

Comment: Читать "Препроцессоры"

Comment: @alexander Нет,  просто хочу понять можно ли обойтись без написания длинного кода foot-l:hover {1}, foot-l:hover {2}...

Comment: Ничего не получится

Comment: Если вам так принципиально воспользуйтесь препроцессором: sass, scss или less

Comment: Спасибо за инф. буду читать

Answer (score 2):

У вас на примере препроцессорный код, браузер такой не понимает

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
footer {
 background:#333;
 height:40vh;
}
a {
color:#fff;
}
footer:hover .lnk1 {
  color:orange;
}
footer:hover .lnk2 {
  color:#00B4D8;
}
footer:hover .lnk3 {
  color:#AB0080;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<a class="lnk1" href="#">Ссылка1</a>
<a class="lnk2" href="#">Ссылка2</a>
<a class="lnk3" href="#">Ссылка3</a>
</footer>
```